# ASP.Net application is getting the intermittent timeout issue post migrating from SQL server to Redis cache

Tags: asp.net, azure, redis, stackexchange.redis, azure-redis-cache

Recently ASP.Net web Form (4.6.2) application migrated the session from the SQL server to Redis Cache. Users are getting the timeout exception frequently. We are not able to find the reason why this is happening.
As per our analysis, the Redis cache server is not sending the response and 17 are already in the queue to be processed. It will be really helpful if anyone can guide us to understand and fix this.

Code Sample :

```
 Session["SelectedItems"] = value;
      //some code
return Session["SelectedItems"] as Dictionary<string, bool>;
```

Azure Plan: Standard - C5
Microsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider-V5
SE.Redis-v2.6.22.40240

Config:

```
<sessionState mode="Custom" customProvider="MySessionStateStore">
        <providers>             
  
            <add name="MySessionStateStore"
             type="Microsoft.Web.Redis.RedisSessionStateProvider"
             connectionString="redis.cache.windows.net:6380,password=XXXXXX=,ssl=True,abortConnect=False,sslprotocols=tls12,connectRetry=5"
             connectionTimeoutInMilliseconds="300000"
             operationTimeoutInMilliseconds="5000"
             retrytimeoutInMilliseconds="8000"
             ssl="true"
             throwOnError="true" />
        </providers>
    </sessionState>
```

Exception :

```
The Message timed out in the backlog attempting to send because no connection became available, command=EVAL, timeout:5000,outbound:0KiB,inbound:0KiB,inst:0,qu:17,qs:0,aw: Fasle,bw: Activating, rs:ReadAsync,ws:Idle,in:0,last-in:28, cur-in:0,sync-ops:125148,async-ops:1,serverEndpoint:xxxxx:6380,conn-sec:37424.94,aoc:0,mc:1/1/0,mgr:10 of 10 available, clientName:winnn(SE:Redis-v2.6.116.40240),(Micrsoft.Web.RedisSessionStateProvider-v1.1.0.0).IOCP:(Busy=0,Free=1000,MIn=8,Max=1000),WORKER:(Busy=5,Free=8186,Min=8,Max=8191),v:2.6.116.40240.
```